# What does this mean: Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

In ASP.Net MVC, in the razor view, you can type this kind of code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

(in this case, it creates a textbox for the field Name of the object which is defined as the type of the model)

Now when i see the definition of the EditorFor method, it is this:

```
EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression);
```

So i tried implementing that kind of method myself, but i realy don't see what this means
**`Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>`**

Who can explain to me what an expression is, and the Func, and the Expression of type Func?

The explanations i found where all so abstract it didn't give me a clue....

Comment: What don't you get? Don't want to give you another overly abstract answer...

Answer (score 7):

The [`Expression<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) class:

> Represents a strongly typed lambda expression as a data structure in the form of an expression tree.

[And](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb506649.aspx):

> The System.Linq.Expressions namespace contains classes, interfaces and enumerations that enable language-level code expressions to be represented as objects in the form of expression trees.
>
> The abstract class `Expression` provides the root of a class hierarchy used to model expression trees.
>
> The classes in this namespace that derive from Expression, for example `MemberExpression` and `ParameterExpression`, are used to represent nodes in an expression tree. The `Expression` class contains static (Shared in Visual Basic) factory methods to create expression tree nodes of the various types.
>
> The enumeration type `ExpressionType` specifies the unique node types.

---

The [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) (and family) of delegates:

> You can use this delegate to represent a method that can be passed as a parameter without explicitly declaring a custom delegate. The encapsulated method must correspond to the method signature that is defined by this delegate.

The family basically encapsulates delegates for functions that have a return value.

---

Taken together, these are expressions that take func delegates typed take a parameter of the model type and return whatever value the lambda returns.

Comment: I think i'm more lost in the expression part. I've tried the `Func` part en i see that i can invoke that. So when i have a function that gets a `Func` as parameter, it's sort of a pointer to a method in a class, and i can execute that method / the `Func`. But the `expression` and `expression tree' thing, i don't get what i can do with it. Especially in this case, why isn't the `Func` enough? isn't the `model => model.Name` also a `Func` which can be used in the `DisplayFor`, so what's the need for the `Expression`. When i look in the watch what the `expression` can do, it doesn't clarify much.

Comment: @Michel - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct

Comment: That makes sense.. but... can you explain me why and how the `EditorFor` uses the `Expression`? Because the property gets send in as Expression, and then what to do with the expression? I think i'm lost at this part 'This tree structure describes what a lambda expression does rather than doing the actual thing.'

Comment: @Michel - Take a look at the other answers there and follow the links - Marc Gravel has a good blog post about the subject, and the  links by LSpencer as well.

Answer (score 3):

Expression is a class that enables you to take a lambda expression and transform it into a syntax tree. It is used by Linq (for example) to convert Linq queries into actual SQL queries. It is highly extensible so you could do other things with it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.90).aspx

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree if you aren't familiar with AST's.

Comment: The wikipedia article is exactly one of those articles which makes no sense to me :-)

Comment: @Michel yacc tutorials go over this a lot because typically, you build an AST in the parser. The concept is fairly simple, for example: an if statement has an expression to check, and a body, so there would be an if node, with child[0] being the if expression, and the child[1] being the if "body" that is executed when the expression result is true. There are node types for adding, subtracting, calling functions, etc. it is simply a tree representation of the source code.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML Helpers use a trick that has been called ["Static Reflection"](http://kharasoft.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/static-reflection-say-what/) that was brought to the .NET framework to support LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework. Basically the Expression captures a Lambda which is verified at compile time (hence the Static) in a syntactic tree. The tree can be walked and can give things like the name of the member that is referenced by the body of the lambda.

Essentially, it's a work around for .NET's lack of a "symbol" keyword like some other languages support.

Comment: What are some languages that have "symbol" keyword? does Java has it?

Answer (score 2):

In this specific example, the generated HTML looks like this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="ActualName" />
```

If the parameter was just a `Func`, you would be able to get value `ActualName`, but not the name of the property you're accessing (`Name`). So, to get that name, you would need it as a `string` parameter (e.g. something like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, "Name")`).

This is not nice, because it means you have to enter the property name twice. Worse, you lose compile-time safety: if the property name changes, you won't get an error on the second parameter.

Comment: There must surely be a way to get (Name) from the expression otherwise how does the built in Method work?

Comment: @ConnorBishop If you're talking about `Delegate.Method`, that that gives you the method that represents the lambda, not the property that's accessed in the lambda.